# Rails 5.2 rendering nothing but only when including stylesheet or javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 5.2 application that has a very weird bug where if I include a stylesheet or javascript tag it will render nothing at all with no errors or failed messages in the console.

Completely Empty Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Actual output:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

I can fix it doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ideas?

The yield is supposed to render `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'landing_app' %>`

And when I just remove the javascript include tag it will still be broken. The only time it works is if I remove both tags. Then the React application will render but obviously without styles which I need for the app.

- I've no caching setup.
- I've deleted the tmp directory.
- I've tried removing turbolinks.
- I've added an h1 tag to the layout and that still
  won't print.
- I've tried disabling the CSS and JS loaders for webpacker
- I've tried removing public/packs

**Edit**

I think I'm on to something. If I delete everything inside of `application.css`, it will render. I think there might be some conflict between application CSS and webpacker CSS. There's not a lot of clarity on why webpacker doesn't have CSS loaders built in. Also, kind of weird the CSS can break an application from rendering entirely.

I've reduced it to a single line, `*= require_tree .` apparently breaks the application. I...I have no idea as to why.

**Possible Solution**

Don't use `*= require_tree .`. Manually, I've having to import each CSS file in. Seems stupid. Oh well.

Comment: What do your automated tests say about the content?

Comment: I'm hitting the route directly in local dev and in the browser the html is just empty head and body tags.

Comment: try to remove `csp_meta_tag` and check again.

Comment: Just tried removing that tag and it still doesn't render. I think it's related to css.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies; this isn't a full answer to the question, but I don't have enough reputation to leave a simple comment. Go figure ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

> There's not a lot of clarity on why webpacker doesn't have CSS loaders built in.

Just wanted to clarify that Webpacker *does* have CSS loaders built-in. Here's a list of the default loaders: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/a2aa7399f4bc2b9ca2cd035bf456a78a054dba07/package/rules/index.js#L9-L14